# BlockMissingException on running Spark job

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I am running a spark job via pyspark, which consistently returns an error:

`Diagnostics: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block: BP-908041201-10.122.103.38-1485808002236:blk_1073741831_1007 file=/hdp/apps/2.5.3.0-37/spark/spark-hdp-assembly.jar`

The error is always on the same block, namely `BP-908041201-10.122.103.38-1485808002236:blk_1073741831_1007`.

When i look in the hadoop tracking url, the message reads:

```
Application application_1505726128034_2371 failed 2 times due to AM Container 
for appattempt_1505726128034_2371_000002 exited with exitCode: -1000
```

I can only assume from this that there is some corrupted data? How can i view the data / block via hadoop command line and see exactly which data is on this potentially corrupted block.

Unfortunately there doesnt appear to be more detailed logs on the specific nodes of failure when looking in the web based logs.

Also - is there a way in pyspark to ignore any 'corrupted' blocks and simply ignore any files/blocks it cannot fully read?

Thanks

Comment: I dont have superuser access on this cluster to run hdfs fsck -list-corruptfileblocks, but is there any other way to view corrupted blocks, or specifically to look into a specific block?

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem?